# Use same cookie many time with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cookies

I need to automate the interface of a tool called Salesforce. Problem, this ihm requires a double authentication with a password which arrives by mail for the first connection.
To solve this problem I used cookies, so to be successful I did a first authent manually to create a cookie file in order to be able to use it for a second connection.
When I run my test a second time, it works fine, I don't need to re-enter my credentials.
But when I want to reuse the same cookie for a third test, it no longer works and I fall again on the authent page, although the cookie has not been modified and is identical.
So, do you know how I can use the same cookie over and over again?
I used the code that is on this url "https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html" to create and load my cookie.
I hope I was clear enough and hoping that someone already has this problem or has an idea
Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into reusing profiles with selenium. plenty of examples here on SO.

Comment: there may be 2 cookies at play here... a "remember me" type, and a session cookie.  If the session expires the session cookie is no longer valid.  It'll depend on how they maintain a session.  (For instance some "token" methods will use a "refresh-token" when a session expires to get a new session token along with a new refresh-token.)  In that case you'd need to store the new session tokens at the end of each run to be sure they're fresh.  (but this still may not retain the session depending on when/if a session times out)

Comment: @DMart I didn't know the profile method.
It actually works better than with cookies.
Is there a way to create a profile and save it in another directory than the default directory?